# How can I animate an input range to change its value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML element input of type range:

```
<body onload="rotar()">
  <img src="#" id="locator" />
  <input type="range" name="points" id="loop" min="1" max="20" data-show-value="true">
</body>
```

It goes basically like this: This page shows images that change dynamically and I want the slider with ID `loop` to change its value, just like the images so it moves according to them.

```
function rotar(){
var slider = document.getElementById("loop");
var locator = document.getElementById('locator'),
    dir = 'static/visor/img/',                   
    delayInSeconds = 3,                        
    num = 1,
    len = 20;
setInterval(function(){
    locator.src = dir + num+'.png';
    if (num === len){
        num = 1;
    }
    else{
        num++;
    }
    slider.value = num;
}, delayInSeconds * 50);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the delay passed to the `setInterval` method, as the delay argument is in milliseconds, to get `2.8` seconds you'd have to multiply the `delayInSeconds` variable by 1000.

> You had some mistakes in your code, you refreferenced the `img#locator` element with the variable name `rotator` the you used the variable name `locator`, which will cause an Undefined variable error. Im my answer I changed the variable's name from `rotator` to `locator`, also I made the delay to 2.8 seconds.

Here's a demo:

```js
function rotar() {  
  var slider = document.getElementById("loop"),
      locator = document.getElementById('locator'),
      dir = 'static/visor/img/',
      delayInSeconds = 2.8,
      num = 1,
      len = 20;
  
  setInterval(function() {  
    locator.src = dir + num + '.png';    
    num = (num === len) ? 1:num + 1;
    slider.value = num;
  }, delayInSeconds * 1000);
}
```

```html
<body onload="rotar()">
  <img src="#" id="locator" />
  <input type="range" name="points" id="loop" min="1" max="20" data-show-value="true">
</body>
```

Comment: I have 20 images, so total time should be 3000 that is why delayInSeconds is multiplied by 50, in order that all the loop lasts 3 seconds

Comment: change it per your requirements, if you find my answer useful, kindly accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any image dir so i just did it with an simple input. please check this http://jsfiddle.net/maxofpower/tAs6V/275/

```
<body onload="rotar()">
 <form ><div>
  <input id="loop" onchange="amount.value=rangeInput.value" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value" type="range" min="0" max="200" name="rangeInput" />
  <input id="box" type="text" value="0" name="amount" for="rangeInput"  oninput="rangeInput.value=amount.value" />
 </div></form>
</body>

<script>
 function rotar() {
 var slider = document.getElementById("loop");                             
  var num = 1;
  setInterval(function(){
  slider.value = num++;
  }, 500);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: @m4rc04 you want update loop input when slider get updated dynamically?

Comment: Yes, I just could achieve that "data-show-value" updates dinamically but I can´t make that slider moves, it just stays stopped.

Comment: how about this : 
       $('#locator').on('input', function(){
    $('#loop').val($('#locator').val());
});

Comment: Is that jquery? unfortunately I can't use it, it must be just javascript.